# Facebook like button show only after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

Im using Angular route for my blog and I wanted to put a facebook like button but I got some problem with it.
The button only show after refreshing the page. Here is my code, I didnt find any solutions.

I included the SDK just after the body tag :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=172565956577844";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And add the button in a partial :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://google.com"
   data-layout="button_count"
   data-action="like"
   data-size="large"
   data-show-faces="false"
   data-share="false">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help :).

Comment: You need to use FB.XFBML.parse() ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse ) after you added the HTML.

Comment: Thanks everything work now.

Answer (score 0):

But I just added a "trick", because otherwise it didnt work :

```
$('.fb-button').click(function() {
     FB.XFBML.parse();
 })
$('.fb-button').trigger("click");
```

the element "fb-button" already existing inside the dom.
If someone got an other solution, I will take it with pleasure.

Thanks !